# Images missing in iOS 4.2 on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, uiwebview, ios-4.2, ios4

I'm developing an iPad app using iOS4.3. It uses a UIWebView and javascript (some jQuery) to do change some images and HTML. It's working fine in the simulator and on the iPad, but I want to deploy on iOS 4.2 as well, so I tried it in the simulator and found that some of the images don't change. For example;

```
$('#sideImage').attr("src","sun.png");
```

does not load the image sun.png. I've tried it without jQuery (using document.getElementById), by changing innerHTML instead of the src and by preloading the images, but none are working in 4.2. I have about a dozen images this happens to, and the poster image of a video tag.

I've checked that the images are in the "copy bundle resources" for the target in xCode.

I don't have an iPad with 4.2 to check on a device, so I thought it might be an xCode bug. I was using 4.0, but I've upgraded to 4.2 today and the problem is still there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the case?  iOS uses a case-sensitive filesystem, so if you refer to `sun.png` and the file is actually called `Sun.png`, then it will work fine in the simulator (on a case-insensitive filesystem), but fail on a real device.

Comment: I checked the case and it's OK.

Comment: Double-check that the files are where you think they are.  `Build | Archive` and check inside the IPA file exactly what you are building.  An IPA is just a zip file, so you can rename and extract it.

Comment: I'm having some difficulty getting at the IPA file. I'm using xCode 4.2 and if I build for archive, nothing is showing up in the archiving section of the organizer.

Comment: I did manage to look inside and everything is where it should be. I'm still inclined to believe that this is an xCode bug when using the simulator for older versions of OS.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember the details, but I had a similar problem that I fixed by constructing a complete URL for the image (including the path to the resource directory).  It seemed that the image wasn't in whatever the UIWebView considered to be its root directory.

Comment: I checked the URL of the resource directory, copied the complete URL and pasted into my jQuery call, but it still won't show the image. I also tried including double slashed instead of single one like others have suggested for accessing local files, e.g. file:////localhost//Users//me//Library//Application%20Support//iPhone%20Simulator//4.2//Applications//58A2EB69-1484-4B6E-8E87-C3626E9E3029//my.app//sun.png

Comment: I also tried using window.location from inside the html file to get the path, splitting the string and adding the 'sun.png' but that didn't work either. The files work fine in Safari and in IOS4.3, so as I mentioned in @Jim's answer, I'm leaning toward thinking its an xCode bug.